# Canoncial tag magento

Tags: magento, seo

I am busy with a magento site, and I have a product in my site and the cannoncial tag is:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="....../product" />
```

But I want my cannoncial tag to be:

```
<link rel="canonical" href=".......category/product" />
```

How can I fix this, I searched on Google, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

That is not something to be 'fixed', it is normal behaviour.

The point of the canonical tag is that your product could appear in any number of categories which would otherwise generate multiple urls for the same product and therefore duplicate content issues.

Because Magento has no concept of a preferred category for a product, the neatest solution is have a canonical url of type http://www.myMagentoUrl.co.uk/myProductUrl.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as PixieMedia noticed, the default Magento doesn't offer the category priority option for the product canonical URLs.

SEO Suite by MageWorx (www.mageworx.com/seo-suite-ultimate-magento-extension.html) has advanced settings for product canonical URLs. With the tool you can set the following canonical URL parameters:

- the longest URL: www.site.com/very-very-ver-looooong-category_name/product_urlkey.html
- the deepest/full category path URL: www.site.com/one/two/three/product_urlkey.html
- the shortest URL that includes a category: www.site.com/one/product_urlkey.html

Also, you can define the individual settings for each product canonical URL - e.g. choose it from the list of all existing URLs or assign your own one.

Whichever canonical URL you may choose, they will be included into an XML and HTML Sitemaps generated by this extension.